# Получение статического размера класса в операторе NEW

Tags: c++

Как получить у класса в перегруженном операторе NEW размер самого класса ( по сути равный параметру size_t в new) но статического/константного типа (для шаблона).

Наивный пример:

```
template <size_t SIZE>
thread_local Bank bank(SIZE);

struct BASE {
    void* operator new ( size_t ) {
        bank< sizeof( *this ) >.Alloc(); // Да только "sizeof( *this )" в операторе new не допускается...
        ...
    };
};

struct A : BASE { 
    int a;
    //BASE::operator new; // Не требуется, так как наследуется от BASE само
};
void abc() { A* a = new A; }
...
```

Comment: `sizeof( BASE )`

Comment: @user7860670 "sizeof( BASE )" - тогда размер будет привязан к BASE, и при наследовании будет некорректный размер производного класса.

Comment: А при чем тут размер производного класса? Этот оператор перегружен для BASE.

Comment: @user7860670 как раз в примере специально прописал "struct A : BASE { int a; };
void abc() { A* a = new A; }". Перегрузка же наследуется вместе с базовым классом.

Comment: Глупый вопрос: а если в операторе вызвать виртуальный метод `size()`? Или не виртуальный, а с реализацией `sizeof(*this)`?

Comment: Погодите, вам же в оператор размер передается параметром.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov "operator new" это статическая функция, соответственно нельзя обращаться в ней к "this" и каким либо не статическим внутренностям класса. Хотя для sizeof(*this) никуда обращаться и не надо, так как вычисляется на этапе компиляции. С точки зрения логики "sizeof(*this)" - является корректной формулировкой.

Comment: Суть не в значении что передаётся, а в том, какого оно типа.

Comment: Тогда следует перегрузить оператор в `A`. Классы с перегруженными `new` `delete` имеет смысл делать `final`.

Comment: Какого типа? Что мешает написать так `void* operator new(size_t size) {
        bank<size>.Alloc();`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Как минимум что так сделать нельзя, с точки зрения языка... SIZE в вашем случае обычная переменная, и её нельзя использовать для инициализации шаблона. А если вы так и сделаете, то компилятор вас безжалостно обругает: "Выражение должно иметь константное значение. Значение параметр "size" невозможно использовать как константу."